# How to find out if logout is clicked on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, logout

This is the code I am using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    alert('You logged out ' + response);
});
```

Also tried `console.log`. Nothing happens.

Comment: I want to execute a callback whenever logout is clicked. I want to log them out of my system.